# aspnet core return json function returning invalid json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I have sales and sales item entity where i'm trying to return some json from controller to front end using return `json ()` function in asp.net core 2.0

here is my controller code :

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSales(int saleId)
{
  SalesModel sales = saleRepository.All().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == saleId);
  sales.Items = saleItemRepository.All().Where(x => x.SalesId == 
  saleId).ToList();
  return Json(sales);
}
```

on the front, using jQuery ajax get call :

```
 function getSale(id) {
     return $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: "/Sales/GetSales",
              data: "saleId=" + id
         });
 }

 $.when(getSale(saleId)).then(function (res) {
      console.log(res);  
      }).fail(function (err) { 
         console.log(err);  
      });
```

**on the console i'm getting json, which is invalid : array ending }]} are missing**

```
{"salesDate":"2018-06-14T00:00:00","saleCode":"1527863276313","notes":"Ok","total":12.31,"status":"Due","discount":0.31,"grandTotal":12.0,"paymentMethod":"Cash","customerId":3,"customerModel":null,"items":[{"name":"hello","price":2.33,"quantity":4,"amount":9.32,"salesId":7
```

[console error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq9cu.png)

**but while I hardcoded the salesItem, it's returning valid json and it seems ok**

```
public JsonResult GetSales(int saleId)
        {
            SalesModel sales = saleRepository.All().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == saleId);
            SalesItemsModel a = new SalesItemsModel { Name = "abc", Amount = 2.5, Id = 1, IsDelete = false, Price = 2.5, Quantity = 1, SalesId = 5};
            sales.Items.Add(a);
            return Json(sales);
        }
```

what am i missing to get a valid json while fetching from database ? this same code is running perfectly on aspnetmvc 5

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetSales(int saleId)
{
  SalesModel sales = saleRepository.All().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == saleId);
  sales.Items = saleItemRepository.All().Where(x => x.SalesId == 
  saleId).ToList();
  return OK(sales);
}
```

There is no need to explicitly convert your sales object using Json method. Also, noticed I have changed the return type to `IActionResult` and returning the `OK` response.

Comment: I also tried that before writing the question here, `Ok()` function also returning invalid json and maybe `sales.Items = saleItemRepository.All().Where(x => x.SalesId == 
  saleId).ToList();`  line making the actual problem here

Comment: Have you tried returning only the saleItems i.e. `Ok(saleItemRepository.All().Where(x => x.SalesId == saleId).ToList())`

Comment: Yes i tried,  also returns invalid json but when i'm returning  only sales without fetching salesItem it works fine. still can't figure what silly thing i'm missing here.

but the some code is running aspnet mvc 5 works great with no issues.

Comment: In Chrome developer tools, switch to Network tab and then analyze `Sales/GetSales` api call. Check if the Response Header `Content-Type` is `application/json` and also check the json response returned from the server.

Comment: Thanks, I found it, the issue was not in `return json()` function, it was with EF core 
`include()` methods. 

Here is the details :  https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5910